# Combinatorics: distributing exams to TAs for grading

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Problem**

The problem statement reads as follows:

> Three TAs are grading a final exam. There are a total of 60 exams to grade.
>
> (a)
> How many ways are there to distribute the exams among the TAs if all that matters is how many exams go to each TA?

**Attempt**

My assumption was that each exam is distinct, since it doesn't make sense to treat each exam as indistinguishable (after all, they are taken by different students). I used the notation of $E$ for the exams, i.e. $E_1$, $E_2$, etc.

- $E_1$: $3$ possible TAs
- $E_2$: $3$ possible TAs

And so on. So I figured the answer would be $3^{60}$.

**Answer key**
[image]

**Question**

Why is this being treated as a combination problem? Doesn't it matter who gets whose exam? Why are they assuming there are $60$ identical exams? Was my assumption wrong?

Comment: 'If all that matters is the number of exams rhat goes to TA', hence all exams are the same

Comment: Oh. That's not how I interpreted that restriction, though. I thought that was in addition to my assumption. All right.

Comment: Just trreat exams as a numbr of bars